# Page load in Selenium webdriver 2.0 - java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How do i make the selenium to wait for the page load
in my application i have tried Thread.sleep(5000); method
some times it is working fine but some times it's not working
Can any one help me out plz

Regards
Srinuvas M

Answer (score 0):

so you can increase the time in some place, where its not working. Secondly, also see - waitForPageToLoad.